# datatype for checkboxes in php

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

What should be the data type that will be entered in phpmyadmin if I plan to use a checkbox as an input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL documentation recommends using tinyint(1) for boolean values, so tinyint(1) is probably the best.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: also remember that 0 inside of if() returns false, so you don't need to hack some crazy if statements to check whether its selected or not. just place the cell into the if statement and you are good

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of related checkboxes that you would like to store in a single column, you might also consider SET datatype, which is similar to ENUM in that you can have names for each of your "options", but SETS lets you have multiple selected named options.